# Rails migration conventional naming

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

when doing migration in rails, I know how to create a model using 'Rails generate model' command. My question here is if I would want to add one more column to the model, does it necessarily need me to give a new migration name as descriptive as below?

For example:

1) I originally have a model named 'Employee' with one column named 'name'.

2) Then, what I need to do is to add a new column named 'occupation'.
So, what I do is I need to generate a new migration as follows:

rails generate migration add_occupation_to_employee occupation:string

I just follow the descriptive naming on which I read from a book, but I got no idea how to name it properly.

My question is: Is there any rule of thumb applying to the naming of  'add_occupation_to_employee'?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Rails is intended to emphasize Convention over Configuration.

So from 'add_occupation_to_employee', Rails automatically takes employee as table and occupation as column.

Answer (score -1):

There is no rule of thumb just name your migration something meaningful like the way you did. For example:

```
add_column_to_table
remove_column_from_table
add_my_index_to_table
```

and so on.

Comment: Sorry sunny I had to down-vote this.  Nothing personal.  See rails does (or at least can) figure out the names as abhidsm shows.  Unfortunately the format is really maddening as more often than not you'll just end up with an 'empty' migration.  When I usually end up doing is just that and then in the migration I can more easily set it to add_column :table, :column, :type, :other_stuff - but that is not the EXACT format there, don't have it to hand, but frequent and annoying problem.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand.

When you want to add a column to a table would you be typing something like rails g migration add_mycolumn_to_my_table ?